# How to correctly set the name of the application?

Tags: android

This is my Manifest file.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start_screen" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tutorial"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tutorial" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignIn"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_in" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

When I am installing the application, I correctly see the name of the application as set in strings.xml file for "app_name". However, it prints the name for "activity_title_start_screen" in my apps tab (Edit: the screen where we see all the applications in the phone). How to solve this?

Comment: what do you mean by 'apps tab'? the action bar?

Comment: No. The frequently used screen where you see all the applications in your phone. There it gives the name for start_screen.

Comment: Hmm. I read several things and check my own app, my "recent-apps-list" shows with the activity label correctly and this seems to be the general consent. It's not well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Change your label in `<application`:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

You have to change the `string.xml` file. In `string.xml` look for a line such as this:

```
<string name="app_name">CustomAppName</string>
```

Change the content ***CustomAppName*** to a desired name.

Then if you wish your app activity title to be different change the label in  `<activity`, by finding it in strings.xml file and changing it to a desired name.

```
android:label="@string/title_activity_start_screen" >
```

---

Another way would be to use a method called `setTitle` and putting this line in your `onCreate`method in your activity.

```
setTitle("My App Title");
```

Comment: That is set correct. This is driving me crazy. Is it possible that it might be an Eclipse bug?

Comment: @user2684198 I could not tell without looking at more of your other code, but you could try the third suggestion in your MainActivity. Try setting the title using the setTitle method.

Comment: I do not want to change the name on an activity. That appears correctly. I want to change the name of the application.

Comment: @user2684198 OK, try cleaning your project in Eclipse to regenerate the resources. 'Project > Clean'.

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
```

Put

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Comment: But that is the name of my Main Activity!

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
```

From your Activity declarations and set the title programmatically in code:

```
mActionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_main));
```

Comment: But isn't that supposed to be the name of my MainActivity? How does it affect the name of the application?